# Can Jenkins build Eclipse projects?

Tags: java, eclipse, jenkins

I thought I had read somewhere that Jenkins supports integration with Eclipse to build Eclipse projects, but now I cannot find any documentation supporting this. Is this possible to do or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You could use Maven builds with [Tycho](http://eclipse.org/tycho/) (see [the Minerva example](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Minerva)).

You could also use [Buckminster](http://www.eclipse.org/buckminster/) to reuse the PDE builds - Jenkins also has a [Buckminster plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Buckminster+PlugIn) for easier configuration. And it is also possible to build Eclipse with Ant, and execute it with Jenkins.

If I have to choose a way, I would suggest Tycho - it seems the most easy to use from the current items, and would forget Ant, as it is not that well supported.

Answer (score 2):

You can run Eclipse build from the command line:
http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_apt_building_with_apt.htm

```
C:\path\to\eclipse\eclipsec -nosplash -application org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild -data %WORKSPACE%
```

And you can add this as a batch command to Jenkins