# How to configure Jenkins to point to local codebase

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, ant, eclipse-plugin, jenkins-pipeline

Let me break down my problem statement in parts:

**What I have:**

1. A Bitbucket repository, say CentralCodebase whose uri is- `ssh://git@bitbucket.org/centralCodebase.git`.
2. Jenkins is already configured, say `https://jenkinsURL/jobs`. I've configured a job **J** there which is pointing to the master version of CentralCodebase repo using ssh uri as mentioned in the point 1.
3. I've also configured Bitbucket post commit hook to trigger my jenkins job whenever there is a commit in the repository.
4. I've configured PMD/Checkstyle/FindBugs/Cobertura/Jacoco plugins, their thresholds are also configured in the job.

   This setup is perfectly working. Whenever there is commit, a build triggers automatically because of hook or anyone triggers it manually by clicking Build now button on Jenkins UI. If all testcases are passed and code coverage and PMD(etc.) thresholds are not broken, build is passed otherwise it fails.

**What I need:**

Say I created a working branch **B** out of master codebase to do some changes at my local. I want to do something like this:

I want to trigger jenkins job J(point 2, either by command or eclipse plugin, not by clicking Build now button from jenkins UI) in such a way that J should build B(branch at my local, not the master version it is pointing to) by applying all the coverage and code plugins configurations.

**Why do I need this:**

So that I can check if my changes are breaking any testcase or PMD/Checkstyle/FindBugs/coverage thresholds. If failed, I can fix the code and check the status again by building it locally but with the same jenkins job configuration without touching the existing live job config. Otherwise, I'll have to commit my changes first, then change branch name in job config followed by build trigger.

**PS:**

I am using ANT and it can't be changed to maven. As of now, when I build changes at local, it runs the test cases, generates code coverage but it doesn't apply threshold criterion that Jenkins apply. It doesn't fail if new changes are breaking PMD threshold or going down the min code covergare threshold as Jenkins would do.

**What I'm looking for:**

Basically, I'm looking for an eclipse-plugin to do this. But anything would work. I've been googling around this but couldn't find anything useful. Here are some resources I followed

- [Can Jenkins build Eclipse projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247344/can-jenkins-build-eclipse-projects)
- [how to make jenkins use an already checked out codebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192862/how-to-make-jenkins-use-an-already-checked-out-codebase)

I also looked into [Mylyn](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/category/free-tagging/jenkins) plugin and its [configuration](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/new/new-3.5.html), [How do I configure mylyn jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769203/how-do-i-configure-mylyn-jenkins), but it wasn't helpful.